# Addition of two decimal numbers represented as string in java

Tags: java, string, addition

When i run this code n iput a decimal number i get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException`:

```
public class Foatadd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1, s2;

        add(s1, s2);
    }

    public static void add(String a, String b) throws NumberFormatException {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        int i1 = a.length() - 1;
        int i2 = b.length() - 1;
        double carry = 0;
        while (i1 >= 0 || i2 >= 0 || carry != 0)

        {
            float x1 = i1 < 0 ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(Character.toString(a
                    .charAt(i1)));

            float x2 = i2 < 0 ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(Character.toString(b
                    .charAt(i2)));

            double sum = x1 + x2 + carry;
            if (sum > 9) {
                carry = 1.00;
                sum = (sum - 10.0);
            } else {
                carry = 0.00;
            }
            int add = (int) sum;
            buf.append(add);
            i1--;
            i2--;

        }
        buf.reverse();

        System.out.println(buf);``
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Where are you assigning values to `s1` and `s2`?? So it's obvious you get that exception because both doesn't contain numbers.

Comment: Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter first  number");
  s1 = in.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter second number");
  s2 = in.nextLine();
  add(s1, s2);   i skip to post this portion to shorten the length of code

Comment: Please tell your input also

Comment: Enter first  number
56.56
Enter second number
56.56
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "."
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 4):

You have a decimal number, but you are attempting to parse one character at a time. One of those character e.g. `.` is not a valid floating point number.

What you need to do is find the decimal place in each number, align the two numbers e.g. you can't add `56.78` and `12.3` but you can add `56.78` and `12.30` this way. After adding enough zeros and the decimal point is in the same place, you can ignore it and pass it to the answer.

BTW You should be able to do this with `int` value alone. Using `float` for basic calculations is likely to make this more complicated.

Comment: when i add two number represented as string its fine but now if someone input a decimal number exception is thrown so i want to add whatever type of input is provided whether its float double or integer.

Comment: @ManishRaaz you are only looking at one digit at time and none of those digits are going to be floating point values. Using `float` isn't going to help you in the way you think it will. Only make the code more complex.

Comment: @ManishRaaz BTW you don't need to use `double`, `Float.parseFloat` nor `Character.toString` either.

Answer (score 2):

Your Strings s1, s2 are not initialized. You have to provide some values here.

Comment: I suspect this is not the OP's actual code as it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void add(String a, String b) {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(a).add(new BigDecimal(b));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.otsi;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Stack;

public class EvaluateStrExpression {

```
public static int evaluateexpression(String expression) {


    // convert string into char array

    Stack<Integer> intvalue = new Stack<Integer>();

    Stack<Character> charvalue = new Stack<Character>();


    char[] Strtokens = expression.toCharArray();




    for (int i = 0; i < Strtokens.length; i++) {

        if (Strtokens[i] == ' ')
            continue;






        if (Strtokens[i] >= '0' && Strtokens[i] <= '9') 
        {


            StringBuilder strbuffer = new StringBuilder();

            strbuffer.append(Strtokens[i]);

            while (i+1 < Strtokens.length && Strtokens[i+1] >= '0' && Strtokens[i+1] <= '9')

                strbuffer.append(Strtokens[++i]);

            intvalue.push(Integer.parseInt(strbuffer.toString()));

        }

        else if (Strtokens[i] == '(')

            charvalue.push(Strtokens[i]);

        else if (Strtokens[i] == ')') 
        {
            while (charvalue.peek() != '(')

                intvalue.push(OprationAdd(charvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop()));

            charvalue.pop();

        }

        else if (Strtokens[i] == '+' || Strtokens[i] == '-' || Strtokens[i] == '*' || Strtokens[i] == '/' || Strtokens[i] == '%') 
        {

            while (!charvalue.empty() && precedence(Strtokens[i], charvalue.peek()))

                intvalue.push(OprationAdd(charvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop()));

            charvalue.push(Strtokens[i]);
        }
}

    while (!charvalue.empty())

        intvalue.push(OprationAdd(charvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop(), intvalue.pop()));


                 return intvalue.pop();

}

public static boolean precedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
        return false;
    if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-') && (op1 == '*' || op1 == '%'))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public static int OprationAdd(char op, int b, int a) {
    switch (op) {
    case '+':
        return a + b;
    case '-':
        return a - b;
    case '*':
        return a * b;
    case '/':
        if (b == 0)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(" we can not divide by Zero");
        return a / b;
    case '%':
        return a % b;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    System.out.println("Enter the  value with expression");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String expr = sc.nextLine();



    System.out.println("Output of evaluateexpression string:::" + EvaluateStrExpression.evaluateexpression(expr));

}
```

}``

Comment: here this is expression solving program and out put is fine but i want add two decimel value. can anyone tell to me?